# How to write a function that takes a list of names and turns it into a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a list of names where the first letter of the last name is the key and then sort it in alphabetical order.

```py
names_list = ['John Oliver', 'Michael Day']
```

the output should be

```py
{
    'D': [Michael Day],
    'O': [John Oliver]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong? Also what happens if there are multiple people with surnames that start with the same letter?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. Based on feedback, here's a different version that handles the case with multiple last name initials. Perhaps can be reduced in the number of lines, but I wrote it out in such a way that it's more readable.

```
names_list =  ['John Oliver', 'Michael Day', 'Jason Derulo']
ini_list = [name.split()[-1][0] for name in names_list]  # Get all of the initials

ini_set = set(ini_list)  # Unique list of names, auto-sorted
list_of_list = [[names_list[i] for i in range(len(names_list)) if ini_list[i] == ini0] for ini0 in ini_set]

d1 = dict(zip(ini_set, list_of_list))
```

Sorted Output: `{'D': ['Michael Day', 'Jason Derulo'], 'O': ['John Oliver']}`

Comment: Couple of notes: 1) The output should be `{'O': ['John Oliver'], 'D': ['Michael Day']}`, this is important if two people have the same first letter in their last name. 2) You can sort a dictionary using `s_dict0 = dict(sorted(dict0.items()))`.

Comment: @RoyCohen Yes, I missed the need for it being a list. And yes, the suggestion of using items() to parse it is more elegant. I made the suggested changes.

Comment: This still doesn't solve issue number 1, if 2 (or more) people have the same first letter in their last name only the last one of them will be included in the output.

Comment: @RoyCohen I recalled this was an issue that some folks brought up though those comments seem to be deleted. The original question never raised the concern if multiple names with the first letter of the last name. I could figure out a way to return a list of all surnames with the letter O and D.

Comment: I believe that OP asked the output to be in lists because of this problem, otherwise what reason there is to use lists that always have only 1 element?

Comment: I've modified my solution.

Comment: Your solution takes more time than mine. The time complexity of your solution is `O(N^2)` (from `list_of_list`) while the time complexity of my solution is `O(N log N)` (from the sort). Unrelated, your solution can be improved by getting rid of some of the list comprehensions that are only used once (`ini_list` and `list_of_list`), and using `zip` in `list_of_list` instead of indexes.

Comment: I deleted my answer and posted a new one, the new answer's time complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this would be to iterate over the names and add them to the correct list (or create a new list if one doesn't exists).
In python, to get the first letter of the last name of some name `name`, we will write `name.split()[-1][0]`.

```py
d = {}
for name in names_list:
    letter = name.split()[-1][0]
    if letter not in d:  # if the correct list doesn't exist
        d[letter] = []
    d[letter].append(name)  # add the name to the correct list
```

This can be simplified using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```py
d = {}
for name in names_list:
    letter = name.split()[-1][0]
    d.setdefault(letter, []).append(name)
```

---

This solution is faster then both previous solutions, its time complexity is `O(N)` compare with `O(N log N)` for my previous answer (deleted), and `O(N^2)` for @astrochun's answer.